# Firebase - cannot resolve symbol

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using Firebase as my Cloud Server. I want to make a simple list of my db but I'm not able to resolve the Cannot resolve Symbol Firebases

The dependencies are:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.4.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.4.0'
}
```

Comment: have you connected to firebase console? Also there is compile and implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.4.0' , shouldnt it just be implementation..

Answer (score 0):

You need to add " apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' " after dependencies in module gradle file and use :

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
}
```

in your project gradle file.

Comment: I added it but it continues to make the error.

Comment: then try to remove" implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.4.0' " and check

Comment: the error persiste.